# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined #2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm making a table using mostly jQuery and [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

I'm getting an error when calling `$('#dataTable').dataTable();` but I don't see why this happens since [I see my table correctly displayed](https://i.gyazo.com/f0c1a48cf75951ae4cfb38b156f968e8.png) **but the DataTable script don't work so the table stays normal, instead having pagination,etc...**

This is the error:

```
jquery.dataTables.js:1197 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
'mData' of undefined
 at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:1197)
 at Function.each (jquery-1.9.1.js:648)
 at init.each (jquery-1.9.1.js:270)
 at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:1194)
 at Function.each (jquery-1.9.1.js:648)
 at init.each (jquery-1.9.1.js:270)
 at init.DataTable [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.js:869)
 at DisplayTable (accounts.js:19)
 at TypesChanged (accounts.js:168)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (accounts.js:171)
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead class="dataTableHead">
        <tr>
            <%--JSON ARRAY CREATES THE TABLE--%>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot class="dataTableFooter">
        <tr>
            <%--JSON ARRAY CREATES THE TABLE--%>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody class="dataTableBody">
        <%--JSON ARRAY CREATES THE TABLE--%>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
 var types = [];
    var amountOfDayEnds = parseInt($('#amountOfDayEnds').val());


        function TypesChanged() {
        selectedGroup = $('#group').val();
        switch (selectedGroup) {
            case "DDA":
                types = ["400","4044","4045"];
                break;
            case "SAV":
                types = ["300","310"];
                break;
            case "MTG":
                types = ["700","710"];
                break;
        }
        console.log("Selected group: " + selectedGroup + ", Types: " + types);
        $('.dataTableHead').empty();
        $('.dataTableFooter').empty();
        $('.dataTableHead').append('<th class="text-center">Day</th>');
        $('.dataTableFooter').append('<th class="text-center">Day</th>');
        var columnNames = [];
        $.each(types, function (index, value) {
            columnNames += '<th class="text-center">Type ' + value + '</th>';
        });
        $('.dataTableHead').append(columnNames);
        $('.dataTableFooter').append(columnNames);
        DisplayTable();
    }

    TypesChanged();

    function DisplayTable() {
        var data;
        //Table
        $('.dataTableBody').empty();
        for(var i=1;i<=amountOfDayEnds;i++) {
            data += '<tr align="center">';
            data += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
            $.each(types, function (index, value) {
                data += '<td>' + '<input class="text-center amountOfAccounts" type="number" value="0" name="amountOfAccounts-' + value + '"  data-error="Please, insert a value"  required></td>'
            });
            data += '</tr>';
        }
        $('.dataTableBody').append(data);

        $('#dataTable').dataTable();
    }
```

Comment: This error seems to origin from accounts.js:-> TypesChanged function. What is this function doing?

Comment: Usually this error occurs when the number of <td> elements dont match in <thead> or <tbody> or <tfoot> elements of your table. Make sure the functions generation these tds are all aligned to produce same number of tds

Comment: try changing `$('#dataTable').dataTable();` to `$('#dataTable').DataTable();`

Comment: @mmushtaq **didn't work**

Comment: @MaVRoSCy the error is on `$('#dataTable').dataTable();` it shows on TypesChanged() because it's called from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this error occurs for two reasons:

- Missing table header.
- Number of `td` elements in the table body differs from number of `th` elements in the table header.

You forgot to add `tr` element for your header and footer rows.

```
$('.dataTableHead').append('<tr><th class="text-center">Day</th>');
$('.dataTableFooter').append('<tr><th class="text-center">Day</th>');
var columnNames = '';
$.each(types, function (index, value) {
   columnNames += '<th class="text-center">Type ' + value + '</th>';
});
$('.dataTableHead').append(columnNames + '</tr>');
$('.dataTableFooter').append(columnNames + '</tr>');
```

See [jQuery DataTables: Common JavaScript console errors - TypeError: Cannot read property ‘mData’ of undefined](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-cannot-read-property-mdata-of-undefined) for more information.